# Make dynamic select box

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a dynamic select box in php MySQL that will return the data in a table or simply in next paragraph.  I am very close, but whenever I select any of the options it will not return any results. I think the problem is within the setup of variable.

**Action script:**

```
if(isset($_GET['Eng']))
{
      $query = "select field2 from karizma WHERE Engine = '".$Eng."'"; // i doubt on this line
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  echo '<table><tr>';

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<td>'.$row["field2"].'</td>';

      }
echo '</tr></table>';
}
```

**Ajax-jquery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#wait').hide();
    $('#Eng').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this);
    if(selected.length == 1)
    {
        $('#wait').show();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"GET",
            url:"action.php",

            data: { 'Eng': selected.val() },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#wait').hide();
                $("#tab1").html(data);
            }
        });

            }
       });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$query = "select field2 from karizma WHERE Engine = '".$Eng."'"; // i doubt on this line
```

With below code and try

```
$query = "select field2 from karizma WHERE Engine = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Eng']) . "'";
```

Comment: can you please tell me at which line it should be replaced

Comment: In the line which you have this comment `// i doubt on this line`, Also make sure you are connected to database, Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select field2 from karizma WHERE Engine = '".$_GET['Eng']."'";
```